# Safely writing to remote database from Android app

Tags: android, database, security

I've figured I have to do some kind of API where the Android app sends parameters to a php-file, or similar.

I'm thinking of an app that would have some sort of high score list. How would I go about making sure that the submitted high score values are in fact achieved through the app? Say that the person achieves 9001 points. Now if this only results in some sort of file.php?score=9001 call, I'm not feeling very secure about people finding the php-location and submitting whatever they like.

Any input on this kind of problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to make this 100% secure since you have no way of verifying where a request came from, but there is a way to make it slightly harder to hack the highscores. It's still basically security through obscurity but it requires digging in to the actual app binary rather than just looking at the network connections.

First, pick a "password" for your app. Instead of sending just the score, also send a cryptographic hash (say, SHA-256 or something) of the password concatenated with the score. On the server side, recalculate the hash of password concatenated with score and check if this matches the submitted hash. If it does not, reject the score submission.
Now this is somewhat more secure than the initial approach because looking at the requests the app makes does not enable you to forge scores. However, looking in to the binary code off the app will still allow an attacker to recover the password and forge score submissions, but this is very involved and probably good enough for your purposes.

Of course, this does not rule out being able to duplicate a score (once the proper hash is known, you can submit a score as many times as you want). If you even want to prevent this, submitting a score would have to go like this: request (random) ID number from server, hash score + ID + password, submit the score + hash, the server then checks whether this hash is good. The server needs to remember the ID number so this is a little more involved to program.
A simpler solution would be to associate each score with the players name, and only allow 1 score per player. Then you could hash password + name + score.

Comment: great.  your answer is going to be handy as a reference to implement security in transactions

Comment: When you say "good enough for your purposes", does that mean that even the large apps with online high score lists (say, Angry Birds) do a similar approach to this? Just, as you mentioned, with a even larger degree of obscurity? Thanks for some good ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon!

It's better to communicate with the server via POST. So you can send an additional parameter, e.g. key, from your app to server and check it there.

The sample of PHP:

```
<?
$key = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['KEY']));

if ($key == 'your_secret_string') {
   //write data to DB
}
?>
```

Comment: When you say "key", what do you mean by that? I'm very uncertain about how much of the source code can actually be discovered by someone trying to decompile or similar. If I had a unique string somewhere in my app and sent this along as a POST, would not someone be able to intercept this and get the key? How would one securely implement something like this?

Comment: This approach alone will not be secure. Anybody can inspect the traffic across the network and easily sniff and extract a key of this nature. A more secure approach would to use standard authentication along with https to secure traffic and access to the remote endpoint.

Comment: You can also send a request with authentication data (401).